# The "Mail to a Friend" action in Careers 2.0 does not URL encode the title, template not filled properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This is the example: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/34890/ui-ux-front-end-web-mobile-apps-development-percipio-media

Click on the "Mail to a friend" link in the top right, the subject and body do not fill properly. There is an ampersand in the title, but it is not encoded in the mailto link so when the email client loads the template, it is incorrect (stops before the ampersand and no link provided).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny enough, the part of that link that was being encoded correctly was the new lines.  A fix for this is on dev and will be pushed either tonight or early tomorrow.

Comment: I initially read that last sentence as 'and the dev will be *punished* either tonight or tomorrow', glad I re-read it.

Comment: @Richard http://i.stack.imgur.com/WslSA.gif :D

Comment: @NickLarsen thank you for addressing this so quickly, i half expected 10 answers telling me i did something wrong and this wasnt really an issue lol